# Typescript: complex self-referencing generic type in functional Monad construction, where it works and where it fails

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads

I'd like to have a method in a class that will flatten nested instances. I've pieced together working bits from around the web and can flatten using an external function; yet referencing that function from within the class will make `Typescript` very slow, buggy, and unstable. The result is that it calculates the wrong type.

Here is the relevant code

```
const Maybe = {
    of: <A>(a: A): Maybe<A> => {
    return isNully(a) ? new Just(a) : nothing
  }
}

// classes
class Just<A> { 
    readonly _A!: A
    constructor(readonly value: A) {}
    fold<B>(whenNothing: B, whenJust: (a: A) => B): B {
        return whenJust(this.value)
    }
    map<B>(fn: (a: A) => B): Maybe<B> {
        return Maybe.of(fn(this.value))
    }
    makeTrouble<B>(fn: (a: A) => B): Maybe<B> {
        return flatten(Maybe.of(fn(this.value)))
    }
}
class Nothing<A> { 
    readonly _A!: A
    static value: Maybe<never> = new Nothing()
    private constructor( ) { }
    fold<B>(whenNothing: B, whenJust: (a: A) => B): B {
        return whenNothing
    }
    map<B>(fn: (a: A) => B): Maybe<B> {
        return nothing
    }
    makeTrouble<B>(fn: (a: A) => B): Maybe<B> {
        return nothing
    }
}

// types
export type Maybe<A> = Nothing<A> | Just<A>

export type IsNestedMaybe<T> = T extends Maybe<Maybe<any>> ? 'T' : 'F'

export type Flatten<T extends Maybe<any>> = {
    T: Flatten<T['_A']>
    F: T
}[IsNestedMaybe<T>]


// values
const nothing = Nothing.value

// functions
const isNully = a => a === undefined || a === null || ( typeof a === 'number' && isNaN( a ) )
const isMaybe = <A>( obj : Maybe<A> | any ): obj is Maybe<A>  => {
  return ( obj instanceof Just )
}

function flatten<T extends Maybe<any>>(x: T): Flatten<T> {
    return x.fold(x, a => {
      if (isMaybe(a)) {
        return flatten(a)
      }
      return x
    })
}

export const head = <A>( arr : A[] ) => arr[ 0 ]
export const safeHead = <A>(as: Array<A>): Maybe<A> => {
  return isNully(as) ? nothing : new Just(head(as))
}

// Example 1 -- everything works

const foo1 = Maybe.of([1, 2, 3])
    .map(safeHead)
// foo1 :: Maybe<Maybe<number>>
const foo2 = flatten( foo1 )
// foo2 :: Maybe<number>

// Example 2 -- wat?

const foo3 = Maybe.of([1, 2, 3])
    .makeTrouble(safeHead)
// foo3 :: Maybe<Maybe<number>>
```

NOTE: if you try this in your own editor and experience slow downs, I suggest commenting out both `makeTrouble` methods and the `foo3` call to `Maybe.of(...).makeTrouble(...)` at the bottom of the code.

Ok, so here is the question

Why does this correctly calculate the type when using the `flatten` function and why doesn't the `makeTrouble` method, which simply calls the `flatten` function? How can I implement a working `flatten` function?

Thanks!

Reference reporting issue for Typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25143

Comment: Looks like this code causes infinite recursion in the compiler: I'm seeing "Error from compilation: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Ct (typescriptServices.js:40)" in TypeScript playground console. I'd suggest reporting a bug...

Comment: Thanks, I've included a link to the issue on GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25143. It actually works for me up to the `makeTrouble` method

Comment: It's `Maybe<any>` in `export type Flatten<T extends Maybe<any>>`. Without `any` you can't really do `Flatten<T['_A']>` because `T['_A']` does not satisfy `extends Maybe<...>`, and all my attempts to do this without involving `any` lead to compiler detecting the circularity and giving errors like `Type alias 'Flatten' circularly references itself` or `'just' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation`. So the general advice holds: avoid using `any`, especially in generic type arguments or constraints.

Comment: This link to a gist showing a working version https://gist.github.com/babakness/037a34826fe770a4d4ebc36a38b04a7f

Comment: I added a link to a working playground in the comments of that gist

Comment: I believe the latest version of Typescript is required